# Querying database inside XSLT to and apply the result to output XML

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I need to query database based on ProductItemId and get ProductName, ProductItemCode, ProductType and ActCode for the below XML. I am using SaxonEE for the transformation. The query should trigger inside the XSLT

My input XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListOfSublines>
   <OrderSubline>
      <OrderSublineNumber>1</OrderSublineNumber>
      <OrderSublineType>ADD</OrderSublineType>
      <OrderlineInstance>120</OrderlineInstance>
      <Lob/>
      <Circle/>
      <Zone/>
      <ProductItem>
         <ProductItemId>10</ProductItemId>
         <AdditionalParams>
            <Parameter name="LOC_CODE" value="25"/>
            <Parameter name="LOC_DESC" value="Kolkata Circle"/>
         </AdditionalParams>
      </ProductItem>
   </OrderSubline>
   <OrderSubline>
      <OrderSublineNumber>2</OrderSublineNumber>
      <OrderSublineType>ADD</OrderSublineType>
      <OrderlineInstance>121</OrderlineInstance>
      <Lob/>
      <Circle/>
      <Zone/>
      <ProductItem>
         <ProductItemId>11</ProductItemId>
         <AdditionalParams>
            <Parameter name="PRODUCT_INDICATOR" value="Mobility Voice"/>
            <Parameter name="RATE CLASS" value="1"/>
            <Parameter name="RRCC" value="Bharti Tele-Ventures"/>
         </AdditionalParams>
      </ProductItem>
   </OrderSubline>
   <OrderSubline>
      <OrderSublineNumber>3</OrderSublineNumber>
      <OrderSublineType>ADD</OrderSublineType>
      <OrderlineInstance>122</OrderlineInstance>
      <Lob/>
      <Circle/>
      <Zone/>
      <ProductItem>
         <ProductItemId>12</ProductItemId>
         <AdditionalParams/>
      </ProductItem>
   </OrderSubline>

</ListOfSublines>
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ListOfSublines>
       <OrderSubline>
          <OrderSublineNumber>1</OrderSublineNumber>
          <OrderSublineType>ADD</OrderSublineType>
          <OrderlineInstance>120</OrderlineInstance>
          <Lob/>
          <Circle/>
          <Zone/>
          <ProductItem>
             <ProductItemId>10</ProductItemId>
             <ProductName>Value from Oracle Db based on ProductItemId 10</ProductName>
             <ProductItemCode>Value from Oracle Db</ProductItemCode>
             <ProductType>Value from Oracle Db</ProductType>
             <ActCode>Value from Oracle Db</ActCode>
             <AdditionalParams>
                <Parameter name="LOC_CODE" value="25"/>
                <Parameter name="LOC_DESC" value="Kolkata Circle"/>
             </AdditionalParams>
          </ProductItem>
       </OrderSubline>
       <OrderSubline>
          <OrderSublineNumber>2</OrderSublineNumber>
          <OrderSublineType>ADD</OrderSublineType>
          <OrderlineInstance>121</OrderlineInstance>
          <Lob/>
          <Circle/>
          <Zone/>
          <ProductItem>
             <ProductItemId>11</ProductItemId>
             <ProductName>Value from Oracle Db based on ProductItemId 11</ProductName>
             <ProductItemCode>Value from Oracle Db</ProductItemCode>
             <ProductType>Value from Oracle Db</ProductType>
             <ActCode>Value from Oracle Db</ActCode>
             <AdditionalParams>
                <Parameter name="PRODUCT_INDICATOR" value="Mobility Voice"/>
                <Parameter name="RATE CLASS" value="1"/>
                <Parameter name="RRCC" value="Bharti Tele-Ventures"/>
             </AdditionalParams>
          </ProductItem>
       </OrderSubline>
       <OrderSubline>
          <OrderSublineNumber>3</OrderSublineNumber>
          <OrderSublineType>ADD</OrderSublineType>
          <OrderlineInstance>122</OrderlineInstance>
          <Lob/>
          <Circle/>
          <Zone/>
          <ProductItem>
             <ProductItemId>12</ProductItemId>
             <ProductName>Value from Oracle Db based on ProductItemId 12</ProductName>
             <ProductItemCode>Value from Oracle Db</ProductItemCode>
             <ProductType>Value from Oracle Db</ProductType>
             <ActCode>Value from Oracle Db</ActCode>
             <AdditionalParams/>
          </ProductItem>
       </OrderSubline>

    </ListOfSublines>
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question, if you have one. This is not a coding service, where you can ask to have your work done for you.

Comment: Hi @Michael. My query is how to connect/query database from XSLT? I am very new to XSLT and any help in this regards will help me to progress.

Comment: I have never used it but Saxon has an extension, see the documentation http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/sql-extension/, that might be able to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use Saxon's SQL extension (which does the 20% of things that 80% of people need, but is by no means complete), or you can write your own extensions using the Java extensibility mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Michael for the hint, I tried SAXON SQL extensions and was able to query database.

This is the XSLT code which is working fine for me:

```
    <xsl:transform version="2.0"
      exclude-result-prefixes="java saxon xsd xsi xsl"
      extension-element-prefixes="saxon sql"

      xmlns:java="http://saxon.sf.net/java-type"
      xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
      xmlns:sql="java://net.sf.saxon.sql.SQLElementFactory"

      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

    >
<xsl:variable name="count" select="0" saxon:assignable="yes"/>
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />

      <xsl:param name="jdbc.driver"   as="xsd:string" select="'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'" />

      <xsl:param name="jdbc.database" as="xsd:string" select="'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test'" />

      <xsl:param name="jdbc.user" as="xsd:string" select="'root'" />
      <xsl:param name="jdbc.pass" as="xsd:string" select="'root'" />
      <xsl:template match="BOOKS">

            <xsl:variable name="sql.conn" as="java:java.sql.Connection">
              <sql:connect driver="{$jdbc.driver}" database="{$jdbc.database}" user="{$jdbc.user}" password="{$jdbc.pass}">
                <xsl:fallback>
                  <xsl:message terminate="yes">SQL extenstions are not installed</xsl:message>
                </xsl:fallback>
              </sql:connect>
            </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select="ITEM">
        <sql:insert connection="$sql.conn" table="book">
            <sql:column name="title" select="TITLE"/>
            <sql:column name="author" select="AUTHOR"/>
            <sql:column name="category" select="@CAT"/>
        </sql:insert>
        <saxon:assign name="count" select="$count+1"/> 
    </xsl:for-each>
<xsl:variable name="book-table">
    <sql:query connection="$sql.conn" table="book" column="*" row-tag="book" column-tag="col"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:message>There are now <xsl:value-of select="count($book-table//book)"/> books.</xsl:message>
    <new-book-table>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$book-table"/>
    </new-book-table>

      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:transform>
```

Hope it help others.

Answer (score 0):

Both SQL and XSLT are special-purpose languages (sharing the trait of declarative types), meant to do one particular thing. For SQL that usually means database manipulation or retrieval or [DDL and DML](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_1001.htm) procedures, and for XSLT that means manipulating XML documents.

Consider using a general purpose language such as Java (an Oracle product), C#, Python, PHP, Perl, VB even R and SAS and still others to handle your Oracle database retrieval needs and XML document parsing and manipulation. Additionally, these aforementioned languages and others maintain their own libraries for XSLT 1.0 processors including XPath 1.0 and XML DOM document libraries. Even more, these languages can call external executables such as Saxon EE via command line (threading or subprocesses) passing needed arguments such as xml or xslt document paths. Finally, these same languages maintain SQL ODBC/OLEDB api libraries including for Oracle databases. By the way, Oracle maintains (like other enterprise level RDMS -SQL Server, PostgreSQL) its own [XML manipulation syntax and features](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb01int.htm) in its PL/SQL dialect.

Altogether, for your needs, consider the following steps:

1. Choose a familiar general purpose language (aforementioned or others);
2. Install its requisite Oracle database connector API (i.e., Java's [JDBC
   driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html),
   Python's [cx_Oracle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle), PHP's
   [PDO DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php));
3. Query database for select data with SQL;
4. Iterate through query data to dynamically create input XML document;
5. Run XSLT with general purpose coding or external executable for final XML output;